# C# and SQL Server 2008 CLR Serialization Problem

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-3.5

I am trying to create a `SqlUserDefinedAggregate` in C# to attach to my SQL Server 2008 instance. I am working with .NET 3.5. Basically, I want to count the number of times I see string values. It does need to be an aggregate function because of the use. The code for the function is logically sound, but when I go to deploy, I get this:

> Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6222, Level
>   16, State 1,  Line 1 Type "GEMCLR.CountTypes" is marked for native
>   serialization, but field  "m_types" of type "GEMCLR.CountTypes" is not
>   valid for native serialization.

`m_types` is a `Dictionary<string, int>`. The outline of my code looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate (Format.Native)]
public struct CountTypes
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> m_types;

    public void Init ()
    {
        m_types = new Dictionary<string, int> ();
    }

    public void Accumulate (SqlString value) { ... }

    public void Merge (CountTypes group) { ... }

    public SqlString Terminate () { ... }
}
```

Comment: What did you do to get this working ? Im getting this exact error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually a Dictionary is not out of the box serializable and this is your issue, there are plenty of articles on how to solve this issue, for example Adam Semel's [How to Serialize a Dictionary or Hashtable in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c.aspx).